# finding and replacing word in string

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char str[80];
   char find[10];
   char change[10];
   char* pstr;
   char* temp = new char[80];
   cin.getline(str, 80);
   cin.getline(find,10);
   cin.getline(change,10);

   pstr =strstr(str,find);

     int a = str.find(pstr);
     int len;
     len = strlen(find);
     str.replace(a,len,change);



   delete []temp;
   cout<< str<< endl;
   return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

> ```
> Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> Main.cpp:18:15: error: request for member ‘find’ in ‘str’, which is of non-class type ‘char [80]’
>    int a = str.find(pstr);
>                ^
> Main.cpp:21:7: error: request for member ‘replace’ in ‘str’, which is of non-class type ‘char [80]’
>    str.replace(a,len,change);
>        ^
> ```

For example,

```
what is your nam / nam / name
```

the output is

```
'what is your name'
what is matter?
```

Comment: You use arrays for C-style null-terminated byte strings, not [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) C++ objects. Arrays aren't "object" in that way, and therefore doesn't have member functions. It seems you're mixing your C and C++.

Comment: Why do you use char[80], then sometimes allocate it, sometimes use the stack, and then use them as objects? Seems like you are not sure of what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

The statement `str.find(pstr);` means *Call the member function `find` of the object `str` with `pstr` as argument*. If you are not sure to completely understand this sentence, I'd suggest you to find [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/5470596).

The thing is, `str` has type `char[80]`, which is not an object of class-type with an available member function `find`. It's a C-style array, not suitable for OOP.

What you need is [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
#include <string>

std::string str;
/* set str */
auto pos = str.find(pstr);
```

Here is the doc of [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string` instead of `char[N]`.

The `char[80]` type is a fundamental type and doesn't have functions.

For the getline, you will need to change it to:

```
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
   char str[80];
   char find[10];
   char change[10];
   char* pstr;
   char* temp = new char[80];
   cin.getline(str, 80);
   cin.getline(find,10);
   cin.getline(change,10);

   pstr = strstr(str,find);

   std::string newStr = str;
     int a = newStr.find(pstr);
     int len;
     len = strlen(find);
     newStr.replace(a,len,change);

  delete []temp;
   cout<< newStr << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two things: please note the markdown usage of code; you used in-line code formatting for each separate line, as opposed to a block of code (backticks on each row vs 4 spaces in front of each row, check my revision) second: Explain **WHY** this code works. Remember that you're not only answering the OP, but the post also has to be readable for future readers, so please, [edit] the answer to explain in text and/or comments in the code why this code answers the problem.